# Can you call a for loop in a forEach method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach-loop-container

First of all, I'm a total beginner in coding and have started a few weeks back, as an persona/intellectual challenge.

I want to know why do I get a null array in this simple script. I think it has something to do with var "i", but I can't find where the error is.

```
function DivEsc() {

var ssIn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Input");
var ssOut = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Output");

var esc = ssIn.getRange(1,3).getValue(); //Escaños en reparto
var i = 0;
var arr = [400, 200,100,50];
var newArr = []

newArr = arr.forEach(num => {
   for (var i = 1; i <= esc; i++){
   return (num/i)
   //    newArr.push(num)
   }
   newArr.push(num/i)
   }
)
Logger.log(newArr)
}
```

Comment: Probably because you return before you push.

Comment: The first line of you inner loop is `return (num/i)`. `return` causes your function to, well return (end).

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything, this the assignment `newArr = arr.forEach(...)` sets `newArr` to undefined. Furthermore you are doing a `return` in the `for` loop thus you are never reaching the `newArr.push`

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.forEach does not return a value, `newArr` will therefore become undefined. JavaScript is a dynamic language where the reassignment of values - even if they don't have the same type - is possible.

Further you return in the first iteration of the for loop, meaning that only the value for num / 1 will be calculated; probably not what you want.

```
// newArr is now undefined!
newArr = arr.forEach(num => {
   for (var i = 1; i <= esc; i++){
   // If you return a value here, the loop will stop after the first round with i = 1!
   return (num/i)
   //    newArr.push(num)
   }
   newArr.push(num/i)
   }
)
```

You could just directly push into `newArr` to make it work.

```
arr.forEach(num => {
   for(var i = 1; i <= esc; i++) {
     newArr.push(num / i);
   }
)
```

If you want to learn more to try out different ways to implement your algorithm, look into JavaScript's functional array methods as e.g. [Array.prototype.map](http://developer.mozilla.org/edeendocsn-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

On a side note: Try using an editor/IDE that handles formatting code for you. In your snippet the formatting (e.g. end of the forEach call) makes it hard to reason about the code.